# How to make MDB Activation Spec contextual properties configurable?

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, jboss-mdb

In our project, we are are using an MDB that listens for a message on a specific queue. It is defined as an annotation.

Example:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = "20")})
```

.

In order to change the value of the maxSessions, the code has to be compiled everytime. Even if i configure it in ejb-jar.xml instead of as an annotation , i need to compile the code and generate EAR file.

Is there a way to make it user configurable(read from properties file) so that the recompilation of code is not required and by just changing the maxSession value to "30" and restarting the jboss, it should be working.

Kindly help.

Reference Code:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "ABCQueue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = "20"),    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="maxMessagesPerSessions",propertyValue="15")})
public class ABCMDB implements MessageListener
{
   ----------- 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to write a gist about Wildfly8 and Websphere MQ integration, allowing to configure and maintain environment contextual configuration for MDB or JMS messages producers.

Basically, I had to declare a jboss-ejb3.xml custom deployment descriptor in my application which use system properties for contextual configuration used by my MDB.

System-properties are configured in wildfly standalone-full.xml file, under system-properties element. So not in a property file, but to my view standalone-full.xml configuration is a good location for such configuration.

Here is the link : https://gist.github.com/remibantos/33c366803f189db9b225

Comment: Rémi, Is this possible with activemq and wildfly?

Comment: I've not tested with ActiveMQ, but I guess so as there is an existing resource adapter which implements JCA (Java Connector Architecture) as described in this article: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/integrate-activemq-with-wildfly. By the way, I've learned that Wildfly 10 now use ActiveMQ, as HornetQ became Artemis which is now part of ActiveMQ umbrella (See http://hornetq.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/hornetq-apache-donation-and-apache.html)

Comment: is this possible with jboss 4?

Comment: With jboss 4 I assume you need extra XML configurations (I've not used Jboss 4 since a very long time), and it's not the same version as Java EE which is implemented. Are you using jboss4 for this (as your question is tagged with "wildfly"?

Comment: I've changed your question title to clarify. You can mark answer as accepted if you think it solves your problem.

Comment: i am migrating application from jboss 4 to wildfly. i am checking possibilities in both.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to modify the number of listeners/maxSessions without restarting the application?  Can I just somehow shutdown the MDB and restart it, picking up the new configuration settings?

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way in Wildfly (I've used it for Wildfly 11).

1. Enable property replacement in annotation by updating "ee" subsystem in standalon-xx.xml or domain.xml

`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
    ...
    <annotation-property-replacement>true</annotation-property-replacement>
    ...
</subsystem>`

2. Define the System Properties, in standalon-xx.xml or domain.xml

   `<system-properties>

       <property name="property.maxsessions" value="50"/>
   </system-properties>`

Or your own properties file  using `-P myconfigured.properties` , while starting wildfly

Or via command line while starting wildfly `-Dproperty=value`

3. Modify MDB annotation

   `@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = 
       "${property.maxsessions}")`

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/developing_ejb_applications/#message_driven_beans-1